# Override product template

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-2.0.4

I want to override magento catalog module product template in my custom theme.

Catalog module template path:

```
<magento_path>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

My custom theme template path:

```
<magento_path>/app/design/frontend/<theme_vendor>/<theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

I've disabled all cache types and tried to clear with command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If I modify magento catalog module template directly my customization goes well.

I did other modules templates (`.phtml`) and layouts (`.xml`) overrides (`Magento_Contact`, `Magento_LayeredNavigation`, `Magento_Search`, `Magento_Theme`) in my custom theme and have gone well.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Magento 2.0.4

Comment: You are doing the right way! Got any changes? Copy styles from vendor `theme-frontend-blank` and less lib in `lib\web\css` to your theme in `app\design\frontend`. Copy layout , templates from vendor of module you need to modify

Comment: You are going the right way. Please see here for more details http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

Answer (score 1):

I had done everything correctly, however I forgot to set my theme in magento panel.